# Why divergence of radius vector equals 3?

Tags: divergence-operator

Ok, I know $div \vec r=3$.

$\vec r = r_x\vec i+r_y\vec j + r_z\vec k$.

$(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}k, r_xi+r_yj+r_zk)=\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial r_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial z}$

Now this supposedly gives $1+1+1$. How do I start seeing that?

Comment: Can you add the full question to your post? As written, it is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Is it alright now?

Comment: I don't understand it.  What is the definition of $\mathbf{r}?$

Comment: @user3600124 I still don't understand. Can you post the full exercise that you are working on, and explain all parts that you have attempted to solve?

Comment: r is radius vector: $\vec r=(r_x,r_y,r_z)$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the radial vector has its component as $$ \vec{r}  =\langle x,y,z \rangle $$
Thus the divergence is $$ \operatorname{div} \vec{r}  = \frac {\partial x}{\partial x} +\frac {\partial y}{\partial y}+\frac {\partial z}{\partial z} =1+1+1 =3$$

Comment: I will memorize it